# NodeJS API DAML Bindings

Tags: daml

we have the following DAML Contract:

data Something = Option A | Option B
deriving(Show, Eq)

data Details = Details
with
id: Text
name: Text
state: Text

template Main with
a: Party
b: Party

```
c: Something
d: Details
```

I know we can do the following for 'a' and 'b' :

fields:{ a: daml.party(a),
b: daml.party(b),}
But how can I write for c and d?

Answer (score 1):

For `d` you can use [`daml.record`](https://digital-asset.github.io/daml-js/latest/globals.html#valuehelpers.record), something like the following:

```
daml.record({
  id: daml.text("youridhere"),
  name: daml.text("yournamehere"),
  state: daml.text("yourstatehere")
})
```

For `c` there is an issue in your type definition. Constructors need to have different names whereas in your example they’re both called `Option`. You can fix this by renaming one or both, e.g.,

```
data Something = OptionA A | OptionB B deriving(Show, Eq)
```

To construct a value, you can then use [`daml.variant`](https://digital-asset.github.io/daml-js/latest/globals.html#valuehelpers.variant):

```
daml.variant("OptionA", yourahere)
```

Comment: ---------------------JS CODE------------------------------

alex: daml.party(alex)
bob: daml.party(bob)

purchase: daml.record(
{name: daml.text(name),
 id: daml.text(id),
 info: daml.party(info)
})

status: daml.variant('A', daml.text('A'),
      'B', daml.text('B))



-----------------QUESTION-------------------------------------

I get the following error upon running node ./file.js 
Reference error: "name" is not defined. 

"name" is party of the Details so have i written in correctly in my node.js code ?

Comment: `name: daml.text(name)` you have to actually specify which name you want to use, e.g., `name: daml.text("Alice")`